# Insert dateTime field into Dynamics AX database through business connector

Tags: c#, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

I have been trying to get my C# program to insert records directly into a [Dynamics AX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_AX) 2009 database using the .NET business connector.

So far I can easly insert a string, int, int64, enum (NoYes), but it fails every time I try and insert a dateTime field (in AX the field is defined as UtcDateTime) with the error:

> The supplied method arguments are not valid.

I'm sure this is something simple that I am just missing.

Snippet of code:

```
    using (axRecord = ax.CreateAxaptaRecord("TempTable"))
        {
            // Fails on this line with error: The supplied method arguments are not valid.
            axRecord.set_Field("DateField", DateTime.Now);

            axRecord.Insert();

        }
```

I have tried passing through as a string and using a `dateTime.parseExact`, etc., but it still does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.

I made a static helper class and included it in my project:

```
public static class MyHelperExtensions 
{    
        public static DateTime ParseDateAsString(this string value)
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("nb-NO");
            var formats = new[] {"ddMMyyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy"};
            DateTime date;
            return DateTime.TryParseExact(value, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date) ? date : DateTime.MinValue;
        }
}
```

Then I could pass in values like this:

```
record.set_Field("StartDate", subscription.StartDate.ParseDateAsString());
```

Now this solution assumes Norwegian culture throughout the system.
The value "record" is of type AxaptaRecord.

StartDate is a field that extends (eventually) TransDate.

I don't see why this shouldn't work for you. 
Here's some other tips:

- Look for errors in the Event Viewer
- Look for spelling errors in you
  variable contained in strings (like
  "StartDate" in my example).
- Start adding breakpoints in both
  Visual Studio and your x++ code.
  :)

Comment: Thanks for this, although it didn't initially work. I recreated the table eventually and got the solution to work. I assume that I created the table incorrectly in the first place. Although both answers here worked I marked this one as the answer since it seems to solve another problem I was facing with multiple datetime formats.

Comment: Glad I could help. :) 

It could also be something wrong with the datatype of that column in the previous version of that table, but that is water under the bridge now.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code?

```
using (axRecord = ax.CreateAxaptaRecord("TempTable"))
{
    var xppDateTime = ax.CallStaticClassMethod("Global", "CLRSystemDateTime2UtcDateTime", DateTime.Now);

    axRecord.set_Field("DateField", xppDateTime);

    axRecord.Insert();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted since this solution works but chose to use the other solution in the end.